# Having some trouble executing "svn log" with Process.Start() in LINQPad

Tags: c#, svn, linqpad

```
Process.Start("svn.exe", "log c:\\work\\lidac\\v1\\ -r {2014-09-01}:{2014-09-24} --xml > c:\\work\\commits.xml");
```

SVN is throwing an error over the >

```
Error resolving case of >
```

I am not sure why. The same command works if I type it directly into the command prompt. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to remove the double backslashes and prepend the string verbatim character @ to you arguments string?

Comment: @Steve I just did now - it gives me the same complaint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing that redirect output symbol to the svn.exe process. He doesn't understand what `> c:\work\commits.xml` means. If you want to do the redirect output to a file, you can either write code to get the output from the process object, or try something like:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/C svn log C:\work\lidac\v1\ -r {2014-09-01}:{2014-09-24} --xml > c:\work\commits.xml");
```